# Do I need a question mark here?

Tags: punctuation, end-punctuation

Does the following need a question mark?

> Lucas’s main concern was who would he take to the apostrophe party.

Comment: It is not a question; hence no need of a '?' mark. However, a bit of restructuring is advised, as, "Lucas’s main concern was who he would take to the apostrophe party."  '...would he' should change to 'he would...'

Answer (score 1):

If it's a statement, it needs no question mark, as statements aren't questions. However, if it's a statement it needs a statement word-order,

> Lucas’s main concern was who he would take to the apostrophe party.

If you're reading that sentence as though it contains a question, with its question word-order, then yes: add a question mark, but you also need punctuation to set the question as a question:

> Lucas’s main concern was, "Who would he take to the apostrophe party?"

All of that may seem overkill if all you want is a simple scene-setter for a list of potential partners, say. Setting it as an explicit question draws attention to the **question itself** rather than the concern about it.